# how to split Mocha.Suite nested functions

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, supertest

How to separate this mocha suite function into 3 different functions? (JavaScript)

```
describe("User login", function () {
    it("user should login", async function () {
      const response = await request
        .post("userservice/login")
        .send({
            email: "user@mail.com",
            password: "123"
            }); 
            expect(response.status).to.be.eql(200);
    });
});
```

That I would get something like this:

```
describe("User login", First());


function First () {
    it("user should login", Second());
  }

async function Second () {
    const response = await request
      .post("userservice/login")
      .send({
          email: "user@mail.com",
          password: "123"
          }); 
          expect(response.status).to.be.eql(200);      
  }
```

This throws an error:

```
TypeError: Suite "User login" was defined but no callback was supplied. Supply a callback or explicitly skip the suite.
```

Apparently, something needs to be passed to the functions, but I can't figure out what (or how).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument of `describe` and `it` should be a callback function. But you passed the return value of the `First` and `Second` functions. The return value of the `First` function is `undefined`, that's why you got the error.

So it should be:

```js
const chai = require('chai');
const { expect } = chai;

describe("User login", First);

function First() {
  it("user should login", Second);
}

function Second() {
  expect(1 + 1).to.be.eql(2);
}
```